# How to synchronize the local DynamoDb and Amazon DynamoDb web service

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

Hello, thanks for your viewing my question first!

I am running the Amazon dynamoDb locally and all databases are saved locally. With the local dynamoDb, I have to show everything with a lot of code, but I feel the interface at web service is much better, in which I can perform operations and see the tables directly and clearly:[image]

So may I ask how can connect them, then I can practice the coding and check the status easily?

Looking forward to your reply and thank you so much!

Sincerely

Comment: You should not be using the local DynamoDB for anything other than testing. Your real server should only be using the real DynamoDB. So, what do you mean by connecting?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot connect them as they are completely separate databases. However, you can put a simple user interface on top of your local DynamoDB database.

I use the SQLite Browser: http://sqlitebrowser.org/. Once you have it installed, open the `.db` file located in the folder where you are running `DynamoDBLocal.jar`. You should be able to see all your tables and the data within them. You won't be able to see DynamoDB specific things like your provisioned capacity, but I think this will give you enough of what you're looking for.

Does this help?

Comment: It helps a lot, though the sqlite is not working perfectly with NoSQL database. It is displaying some unreadable letters in some columns.Thank you very much!!

Comment: I'm assuming that those are the "index" columns, right? If so, that is expected.

Comment: @Spider Since I answered your original question, would you mind upvoting my response and marking it as the answer? I'd appreciate it, thanks!